# jQuery merge objects and json_encode

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

I am trying to merge two objects in jQuery.

first object:

```
var rules1 = {  
    firstname: { required: true, minlength: 3 },
    lastname: { required: true, minlength: 3 }
};
```

second object:

```
var rules2 = {  
    test1: { required: true, minlength: 3 },
    test2: { required: true, minlength: 3 }
};
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
var merged = {  
    firstname: { required: true, minlength: 3 },
    lastname: { required: true, minlength: 3 },
    test1: { required: true, minlength: 3 },
    test2: { required: true, minlength: 3 }
};
```

I also need to know how might look like the PHP array for `rules1`, because this object will be tranformed with `json_encode` function.

Comment: These are objects, not arrays. In PHP you just create an associative array: `$arr = array('firstname' => array('required': true, ...))`. Read more about arrays in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

You can merge them doing this:

```
var merged =  $.extend(rules1, rules2);
```

If you want build it from php your object will be:

```
$rules = new stdClass;
$rules->test1 = new stdClass;
$rules->test1->required = true;
....
```

Personally, in PHP I prefer to work with arrays. Then they can be converted to stdClass recursevely by using some custom functions. You can find one of these here:

http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass

Comment: There is no need to use `stdClass` here at all..